# QueryString from AJAX call to controller action, inside custom ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a logging handler for a project.  I'm using a custom ActionAttribute (LogAction) to read the request to log data.  However, I've only been able to grab the Controller and Action values.  I've been looking for about an hour and I think the data I need exists somewhere in `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString` but I'm having no luck pulling anything at all from that.  It's always empty, or appears to be at the least.  I've also looped through all of the `RouteData.Values` collection and the only things that ever appear in there is the Controller and the Action values.  I've tried logging the whole URL and the RawURL, but the QueryString is nowhere to be found.  What am I missing?

Controller:

```
 [LogAction]
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetCustomer (int customerId)
 {
     //do stuff
     return Json(json);
 }
```

Attribute:

```
public class LogActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
        var action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];
        var parameters = ??;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

JS function to call the controller action (AJAX):

```
self.getCustomer = function () {
    var data = { customerId: self.data.viewingCustomerId() };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Customers/GetCustomer",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (returnedData) {
             //do stuff
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ActionParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.actionparameters?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ActionExecutingContext_ActionParameters) on `ActionExecutingContext`:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
    var action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];
    var parameters = filterContext.ActionParameters["customerId"]; // access action parameters 
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It took a little bit of tweaking but this allowed me to do exactly what I needed.  However, I think it's worth noting that I would always get a null value when casting the `ActionParameter` to a string us `as string`.  I ended up having to call the `ToString()` in order to get the actual value.  Lastly, I could not got the Visual Studio debugger to actually show me the values the way yours is, but I believe this is a quirky behavior of VS, and not related to the answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @TylerSells thanks for sharing and glad it at least help you get started in the right direction. FYI I am using VS 2019, not sure which version you are on.

Comment: I am on 2019 as well.  Its an odd behavior that is best surmised as sometimes it will show it, other times it skips it entirely.  It seems to be related to how/if I reference the variables later on in the code or not.  Very strange, but in the end, not a big deal and not very useful for the question.